# Javascript hide show div - Have div show by default

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

I have a script that I created to show a `div` on-click of an `<a>` tag. However, what I would like to know is if anyone has an easy solution to use this same script but allow a select `div` to show on default? My script:

```
var portletToHide = new Array(
    'p_p_id_1_WAR_webformportlet_INSTANCE_P0j8_',
   'p_p_id_1_WAR_webformportlet_INSTANCE_RPu7_',
   'p_p_id_1_WAR_webformportlet_INSTANCE_6a0F_',
   'p_p_id_1_WAR_webformportlet_INSTANCE_Ta1B_',
   'p_p_id_1_WAR_webformportlet_INSTANCE_Cg3y_');

for(a=0;a<portletToHide.length; a++){
    document.getElementById(portletToHide[a]).setAttribute('style', 'display:none; visibility:hidden;')
}

function display(id, id2){

    for(a=0;a<portletToHide.length; a++){
        document.getElementById(portletToHide[a]).setAttribute('style', 'display:none; visibility:hidden;')
    }

    document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('style', 'display:block; visibility:visible;')

    if(id2){
        document.getElementById(id2).setAttribute('style', 'display:block; visibility:visible;')
    }

    $target =$('#'+id);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({'scrollTop': $target.offset().top}, 900, 'swing');
}
```

Comment: that different items in the array at the top are my div ID's

Comment: It would be much better to use classes (className) and toggle classname, that inside have `.hidden { display: none; }` and you will be able to share the css etc.
Initially you can have your HTML generated with `class='hidden'`

Comment: How is this "select `div`" determined? You could just have an `if` statement in your first loop to not hide the portlet you want shown.

Comment: I am using     'onclick="display('p_p_id_1_WAR_webformportlet_INSTANCE_C0f0_'); return false;"' inside an '<a>' tag

Answer (score 0):

This uses HTML 5 `data-` attributes to allow you to select which `div` to toggle. Below you can use either vanilla Javascript or jQuery.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="mydiv">toggle mydiv</a>
<div id="mydiv">
    mydiv
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function toggleDiv(evt) {
    var link = evt.target;
    var toggle = link.getAttribute('data-toggle');
    var div = document.getElementById(toggle);

    div.style.display = (div.style.display == 'none')
        ? 'block'
        : 'none';

    if(evt.preventDefault)
        { evt.preventDefault(); }
    if(evt.returnValue)
        { evt.returnValue = false; }

    return false;
}

var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a')

for(var i=0,l=links.length;i<l;i++) {
    var toggle = links[i].getAttribute('data-toggle');
    if(toggle !== null && toggle != '' && document.getElementById(toggle)) {
        if(links[i].addEventListener)
            { links[i].addEventListener('click',toggleDiv,false); }
        else if(links[i].attachEvent)
            { links[i].attachEvent('onclick',toggleDiv); }
        else
            { links[i].onclick = toggleDiv; }
    }
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('a[data-toggle]').each(function(i,link){
    var a = $(link);
    var toggle = a.attr('data-toggle');
    var div = $('#'+toggle);

    if(div.length) {
        a.click(function(){
            div.toggle();
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See if it's possible to render the HTML with class 'hidden'.

index.css

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
    /* no purpose combined with display none */
    /* visibility: hidden; */
}
```

index.js

```
var portletsToHide = [
    'p_p_id_1_WAR_webformportlet_INSTANCE_P0j8_',
   'p_p_id_1_WAR_webformportlet_INSTANCE_RPu7_',
   'p_p_id_1_WAR_webformportlet_INSTANCE_6a0F_',
   'p_p_id_1_WAR_webformportlet_INSTANCE_Ta1B_',
   'p_p_id_1_WAR_webformportlet_INSTANCE_Cg3y_'];

function setPortletsVisibility( visible ) {

    for( var a=0; a < portletToHide.length; a++ ){
        setElementVisibility( portletToHide[a], visible );
    }
}

function setElementVisibilityById( elementID, visibility ) {

    var className = visible
        ? ""
        : "hidden";

    document.getElementById( elementID ).className = className;
}

function display(id, id2){

    setPortletsVisibility( true );

    setElementVisibilityById( id, true );

    if(id2){
        setElementVisibilityById( id2, true );
    }
}

function someFunction( id, id2 ) {

    display( id, id2 );

    $target = $( '#' + id );

    $('html, body').stop().animate({'scrollTop': $target.offset().top}, 900, 'swing');
}

// Default
setPortletsVisibility( false );
```

Please note that I dont do jQuery addClass/removeClass which might cause disturbances.